# Are quotients of null sequences convergent if they are bounded?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $0<a<b<1, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the sequence

$$c_n := \bigg\{\begin{array}{ll} 
     a^n & n \text{ odd} \\
     b^n & n \text{ even}
\end{array}\bigg\}$$

On a problem set we had to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{c_{2n}}{c_{2n-1}}}$$

doest not exist in $\mathbb{R}$.

My first idea was that $(a^n)_n$ and $(b^n)_n$ are clearly null sequences and with the algebraic limit theorem follows

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{c_{2n}}{c_{2n-1}}} = \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}{c_{2n}}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}{c_{2n-1}}} = \frac{0}{0}$$

Which shows the limit doesnt exist in $\mathbb{R}$. But this is obviously wrong because the theorem is only applicable if the limit of the denominator is not null. So  I found out that the solution here is that the quotient of $c_n$ is not bounded and therefore there is no limit in $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is though: Are in general quotients of null sequences convergent if they are bounded?

Comment: The limit does not exist since $c_{2n}=b^{2n}$ and $c_{2n+1}=a^{2n+1}$, so $\frac{c_{2n}}{c_{2n+1}}=\frac{b^{2n}}{a^{2n+1}}=\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{2n} \rightarrow \infty$, since $\frac{b}{a} > 1$.

Comment: Your conclusion of $\frac00$ does **NOT** show that the limit doesn't exist -- merely that taking limits in the numerator and denominator separately was a dead end. For example, if we change the setup slightly such that $a=b$ then the limit certainly exists (and it is $a$), but taking the limit separately on both sides of the fraction bar will still lead to $\frac00$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not guaranteed to converge if the quotients of null sequences are bounded; take for example: $$a_n=\frac{\sin n}{n}\qquad\text{and}\qquad b_n=\frac{1}{n}.$$ Then both are null, but $\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\sin n$. This is definitely bounded, but it isn't convergent.

Answer (score 0):

We have $c_{2n}=b^{2n}$ and $c_{2n-1}=a^{2n}/a$. Hence

$\frac{c_{2n}}{c_{2n-1}}=a(\frac{b}{a})^{2n}$. Since $b/a>1$ the sequence $(\frac{c_{2n}}{c_{2n-1}})$ is divergent.

Comment: This isn't a response to his question, only a response to the motivation for his question.

Comment: What ? The OP wrote: "we had to show that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{c_{2n}}{c_{2n-1}}}$ does not exist in $ \mathbb R$"